# Maximum time() | PHP

Tags: php, datetime, date, time

It's kind of a silly question, but what would be the maximum INT value of a `time()` and it's future date, e.g.

> 1st January 2999

Would time() ever get to that value? Going for a large `time()` value would return this:

> Thu 1st Jan 1970 1:00AM

A normal int date

> 1287320788 - outputs today's date: Sun 17th Oct 2010 2:06PM

But I'm only curious for the biggest int date and the last date.

Comment: For MySQL, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it

Comment: That link also has good background info on the PHP side

Comment: Has that been fixed recently in PHP's `time()`?
The biggest value it can make to a date is now `9223372036854772207` (`04.12.292277026596 15:30:07`) (very close to the 64 Bit Integer max value)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The last 32-Bit Integer timestamp will be reached January 19, 2038. This is known as the [Year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Comment: Thanks for this Pekka. Will this ever be solved once we nearly reach to it?

Comment: @YouBook if PHP still exists by then, probably. It's going to be easy to fix by switching the underlying system to larger INTs - Won't be much of a problem thanks to PHP's weak typing. Alternatively, use `DateTime` as suggested by Gordon

Comment: Basically the problem will solve itself by definition since 2038 is max int in 32-bit system and most computers are already 64-bit which means waaaay more range in terms of integers...

Answer (score 40):

PHP stores the highest integer number it can represent in the `PHP_INT_MAX` constant:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', PHP_INT_MAX); // 2038-01-19 04:14:07
```

If you want to work with dates beyond that, consider using the [DateTime API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php), e.g.

```
$dt = new DateTime('1st January 2999');
$dt->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 day'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2999-01-02 00:00:00
echo $dt->format('U');           // 32472226800
```

Comment: Yup, using `DateTime` and - on mySQL side - the `DATETIME` field type fixes the issue completely.

Answer (score 8):

Remember, the Y2038 problem does not apply on 64-bit systems.

Comment: Mmm, are you sure? Will PHP's internal handling of integers turn to 64-bit automatically?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but it seems to roll over on my box... :-)

Comment: 64-bit will be okay for the next ~300 billion years.

Comment: Be careful.  The Y2038 problem always applies on Windows systems.
"64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, except for Windows, which is always 32 bit."
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Well if I remember correctly, XAMPP on Window still uses 32 bit integers even on 64 bit machines.

Answer (score 2):

DateTime seems to use 32bit on 64bit servers, too.
So you get into trouble.

I've solve it this way:

```
new DateTime("99999/12/31 00:00:00");
```

Because, the date overflows the maximum length for DateTime, date use the maximum possibel value and returns a DateTime-object like this (inspected with var_dump) :

```
object(DateTime)#9 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2031-09-12 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } }
```

I'm not sure if it differs with the versions of PHP. I've tested it with version 5.4.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way I know is to get tomorrow's date:

> date("Y-n-j", strtotime("+1 day"))

`date("Y-n-j", PHP_INT_MAX)` on 64bit-systems gives potential dangerous value: `292277026596-12-4`

Answer (score 2):

On 64-bit platforms `PHP_INT_MAX` does not reflect maximum INT value for 32-bit platforms. Here's how to get it:

```
$max32bitInt = PHP_INT_SIZE == 4 ? PHP_INT_MAX : PHP_INT_MAX>>32;
```

If you're always using 64-bit platform, just use:

```
PHP_INT_MAX>>32
```