# PHP Compare datetime values

Tags: php, datetime

In my PHP application I'm trying to compare date time values like the following:

```
if($datetime_from_db < date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
{
    // then do something
}
```

Both values are in the same format. What I can't figure out is why it only compares the date and ignores the time. Both the date and the time values are important for me but I don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 23):

Comparing a **string** like `"2011-02-14 15:46:00"` to another **string** doesn't actually compare **dates**, it compares two strings according [string parsing numeric rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). You will need to compare actual numeric timestamps:

```
strtotime($datetime_from_db) < time()
```

Comment: So I can do: strtotime($datetime_from_db) < strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) ? Will that work?

Comment: @dtn Yes, but `strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))` is the same as [`time()`](http://php.net/time).

Answer (score 9):

If you want this to work with dates past 2038, you can't use strtotime() or time().

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it) for the explanation.

A better approach:

`new DateTime($datetime_from_db) < new DateTime();`

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
$today = date("m-d-Y H:i:s");
$thisMonth =date("m");
$thisYear = date("y");
$expectedDate = $thisMonth."-08-$thisYear 23:58:00";
//pr($today);
//pr($expectedDate);


    if (strtotime($expectedDate) > strtotime($today)) {
        echo "Expected date is greater then current date";
        return ;
    } else
        {
         echo "Expected date is lesser then current date";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where we use `strtotime`. I give two examples.
First one comparing the whole timestamp. Second one is just compare the date.

```
<?php
$date = "2022-10-06 17:49:10"; // string. can set any current timestamp

#example 1 - compare the date and time Y-m-d H:i:s
if(date("Y-m-d H:i:s" , strtotime($date)) >= date("Y-m-d H:i:s")){
    echo "the date checked is bigger than today";
}else{
    echo "the date checked is smaller than today";
}

#example 2 - compare the date only Y-m-d 
if(date("Y-m-d" , strtotime($date)) == date("Y-m-d")){
    echo "same day is true";
}else{
    echo "same day is false";
}
```