# how to find the spacific value to an multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql

Example - 
Assume we have the following 2-dimensional array-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [order_id] => 246
            [court_price_id] => 1048
            [time_from] => 15:30
            [time_to] => 16:00
            [booking_date_from] => 2018-03-28
            [booking_date_to] => 2018-03-28
            [court_price] => 350
            [booking_status] => booked
            [created] => 2018-03-28 15:19:34
            [pricetype] => hour
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [order_id] => 246
            [court_price_id] => 1049
            [time_from] => 07:00
            [time_to] => 07:30
            [booking_date_from] => 2018-03-29
            [booking_date_to] => 2018-03-29
            [court_price] => 350
            [booking_status] => booked
            [created] => 2018-03-28 15:19:34
            [pricetype] => hour
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [order_id] => 247
            [court_price_id] => 1048
            [time_from] => 07:00
            [time_to] => 07:30
            [booking_date_from] => 2018-03-28
            [booking_date_to] => 2018-03-28
            [court_price] => 350
            [booking_status] => booked
            [created] => 2018-03-28 15:19:51
            [pricetype] => hour
        )

)
```

I tried:-

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");

foreach($bookdata as  $values) 
{
    if($values['booking_date_from'] == $date)
    {
        echo "1";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "2";
    }
}
```

i want to if date is preset in array then print 1and if date is greater than current date then print 2.

Comment: Why do you have 2 arrays? `$bookdata` is the first array?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus no, the second Array Syscall mentiones got nothing to do with multidimensional array - it seems like another "print_r" of a second array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Compare datetime values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989410/php-compare-datetime-values)

Comment: @MehrdadEP its not a date compare problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
I got Answer - 


$flag = 0;
                    if(count($bookdata) > 1){

                        foreach ($bookdata as $key => $value) {
                            $date = strtotime($value['booking_date_to']);
                            if($date > $today){
                                $flag = 1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        $id = $bookdata[0]['order_id'];
                        if($flag == 0){
                            $qry = "Update payments set booking_status=1 where id=".$id;
                            $results=mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
                        }

                    }else{

                        $date = strtotime($bookdata[0]['booking_date_to']);
                        $id = $bookdata[0]['order_id'];

                        if($date < $today){
                            $qry = "Update payments set booking_status=1 where id=".$id;
                            $results=mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
                        }

                    }
```