# a curious mysql timestamp insert

Tags: mysql, insert, timestamp

I stumble upon a mysql timestamp insert problem with the date value larger than current date
now the following step is

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
`ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`test_time`TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
); 

INSERT INTO foo(test_time) VALUES('2038-01-19 11:14:08'); // fail
INSERT INTO foo(test_time) VALUES('2038-01-19 11:14:07'); // ok
INSERT INTO foo(test_time) VALUES('2038-01-18 23:59:00'); // ok
INSERT INTO foo(test_time) VALUES('2039-01-01 00:00:00'); // fail
```

fail means the test_time value is 0000-00-00 00:00:00
my timezone is UTC+8
I want to know whether 2038-01-19 11:14:07 is the max timestamp of mysql support,what's the meaningful moment of this time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it explains it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To store higher values for dates you must use `DATETIME` datatype.

`TIMESTAMP` has a range from `'1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC`

`DATETIME` has a range from `'1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

As suggested by @Joachim Isaksson: [PHP & mySQL: Year 2038 Bug: What is it? How to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it)