# How can I convert timestamp of year 2038 to date in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP & mySQL: Year 2038 Bug: What is it? How to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it)

I met problem when converts timestamp (of year of 2038 or above) to date in PHP, it always shows year  of 1901 instead 2038 or above. But everything works correctly when converts timestamp of year < 2038. Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because of the  limit of INT datatype on 32 bit machine

[image]

Solution

1. Use long data types (64 bits is sufficient)
2. For MySQL, store dates as DATETIME rather than TIMESTAMP

Comment: Thank you for answering. But Is there any solution on 32 bit machine.

Comment: @Tuan Use long data types (64 bits is sufficient)and 
For MySQL, store dates as DATETIME rather than TIMESTAMP

Comment: wow.. your solution #1 and #2 are complete copy-paste from the other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it).