# PHP strtotime() with relative format returns strange values

Tags: php

```
echo date("Y/m/d", strtotime("third monday of february 2037")); //2037/02/16
echo date("Y/m/d", strtotime("third monday of february 2038")); //1970/01/01
```

The PHP version is 5.6.3. Thanks

Comment: 32-bit signed integer timestamps have a limited range - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it

Comment: You're running into the [Year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). A possible solution for PHP is discussed [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851138/how-can-i-convert-timestamp-of-year-2038-to-date-in-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

32-bit signed integer timestamps have a limited range

Quoting from the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer.)

This is why [DateTime objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) are a better way to handle dates and times

Answer (score 1):

From [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) doc,

**Note:**

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec
>   1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the
>   dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit
>   signed integer.)

You can try this way using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class

```
$date = new DateTime('third monday of february 2038');
echo $date->format('Y/m/d');
```