# How convert field from timestamp to datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a legacy database where there is table that has fields:
start_date TIMESTAMP,
expiration_date DATETIME.

It cause issues with some queries if database is used on database with different timezones.
So to avoid them, I want to convert start_date to DATETIME. How could I safely convert from TIMESTAMP to DATETIME?  Won't I lose any data if I change type of start_date from TIMESTAMP to DATETIME? How will mysql convert dates TIMESTAMP to DATETIME?

Answer (score 15):

This is how I would do it:

1) Create a new `datetime` column

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN mydatetime DATETIME;
```

2) Update this column using the timestamp values

```
UPDATE mytable SET mydatetime=FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mytimestamp));
```

3) After a few integrity checks, delete the `timestamp` column

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN mytimestamp;
```

This should be safe enough for you, as you can keep the original `timestamp` column as long as you want.

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea8d0d/1) example.

Comment: @Oleg Isnt'it what I wrote? I don't understand the meaning of your comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, I accidentally printed it. I'll delete it. I simply wanted to ask how will this query convert timestamp date? Will I have issues if dates were saved in different time zones?

Comment: I don't think so, but the best thing you have to do is try it and check if it works like you want before deleting the old `mytimestamp` column.

Comment: The problem I see is that dates for different zones can be in different times zones, but converted datetime will be in current time zone of mysql server. For example, if record 1 saved date in timzeone1, record2 in timezone2, and time of server timezone1, timestamp in timezone2 will be incorrectly converted to datetime in timezone1 although expired_date is saved in timezone2. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I think I do but I don't know if it's possible to do what you want in that case: I don't think it is possible to retrieve the timezone in which a timestamp had been recorded in. Therefore, you won't be able to use it to convert to the correct datetime/timezone. I may be wrong though, but I don't see how to do it in that case...

Comment: You don't need `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`:  
`UPDATE mytable SET mydatetime=FROM_UNIXTIME(mytimestamp);`  
Thanks, it worked for me.

Comment: @AlmirSarajčić I've just tried without `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` on MySQL 5.6, the result is always `null` [(test on sqlfiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8317f/1)

Comment: My bad. I was using int column instead of timestamp, so it's different for me. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Isn't safe to use ALTER TABLE... MODIFY?

Answer (score 12):

In MySQL you can simply change the datatype from `TIMESTAMP` to `DATETIME` with no loss of data:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY start_date DATETIME;
```

Comment: Verified. I first did a verification on a duplicated table and ran the `ALTER TABLE` on the duplicate, then on the original. Was done in seconds and no issues. Now future dates (TLS root certs have long `until` dates) are stored safely. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a query to find rows and convert start_time field to **DATETIME** with **date()** function.

Then change field type to **DATETIME**.

Next update field with new value stored in your var.

For example:

```
<?PHP
//.. your codes like connection & ...
// my_table is your table name.
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table");
$stored = array();
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $stored[++$i] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row["start_date"]);
}
mysql_query("alter table my_table modify start_date DATETIME;");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table");
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    // Id is your primary key.
    mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET start_date='" . $stored[++$i] . "' WHERE id='" . $row['id'] . "'")
}
```