# Is it possible to convert string 14 into 2014 in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have an array formed from a string (2014/15):

```
$arr = explode("/", $Years, 2);
```

..and then two strings:

```
$frstHalfYear = $arr[0];
$secHalfYear = $arr[1];
```

..the output is following:

```
for $frstHalfYear: 2014
for $secHalfYear: 15
```

My question is : is it possible to convert `15`  into a full year like `2014`. 
This:

```
date("Y", strtotime($secHalfYear))
```

obviously is not working. The simple way would be to add `20`at the start of the string, but I was wondering if there is some more generic way..

Thank you

Comment: Does it get any more generic than what you already proposed?

Comment: Just prepend `20` and you should be fine for the next 85 years.

Comment: Yeah.. it will sound ridiculous, but what if it would be say.. 2099 and 2100...

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae And people thought it was safe to assume years started with 19__...

Comment: I'm probably looking to far ahead...

Comment: *"Yeah.. it will sound ridiculous, but what if it would be say.. 2099 and 2100"* - If that's based on someone's life, or a warantee, then that is soon to be outlived ;-) I won't live that long to reap the benefits.

Comment: `15 + 2000`. don't do `'20' . 15`, because at some point your code will be spitting out `20100`

Comment: Now that looks better  ..

Comment: @MarcB I'd argue that the chances that PHP is still used in 2100 are slim. But I'd consider creating something that you know will break bad practice as well.

Comment: @Jonathan: never say never. we're already getting bit by the y2038 bug in various "future dealings" stuff.

Comment: @Jonathan To further Marc's comment about the y2038 bug, have a read here http://stackoverflow.com/q/2012589/ on the subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the most generic solution I can think of:

```
$secHalfYear = substr($frstHalfYear,0,-strlen($secHalfYear)).$secHalfYear;
```

Basically, this will take the `20` from `2014` and stick it before the `15` to make `2015`.

It even supports `2099/100` format! But more importantly, you can write `2014/2015` and it will work just fine too.

Comment: Works great!! Thanks!!  Will check back in 2100 to see how it'll manage.. :-)

Comment: @Dims You've evidently found the fountain of youth ;-)

Comment: @Dims Your secret is safe with me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want something completely over the top: http://ideone.com/LzcgA3

```
var_dump(getDates('2014/15'));
var_dump(getDates('1999/12'));
var_dump(getDates('14/15'));


function getDates($dateRange) {
    $exp = explode('/', $dateRange);

    $startYear = $exp[0];
    // Cater for 14/15
    if ($startYear < 100) $startYear += date('Y') - date('y');

    $endYear = $exp[1];

    // If passed the full year, just use that
    if ($endYear < 100) {
        $shortStartYear = substr($startYear, 2, 2);
        if ($shortStartYear > $endYear) {
            // Jumping millenium
            $endYear += $startYear - $shortStartYear + 100;
        } else {
            // Same millenium
            $endYear += $startYear - $shortStartYear;
        }
    }

    return array('from'=>$startYear, 'to'=>$endYear);
}
```

This will actually cater for most dates.  But appreciate if it's a little excessive ;)

Comment: Woah... That's a massive one... But it should cover all cases... Thanks a lot Pete!

Comment: `if ($startYear < 100) $startYear += 2000;` is basically a "Y2.1K" bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score -1):

```
$secHalfYear = $frstHalfYear + 1;
```

You have to make certain assumptions to expand a date appropriately, but I don't believe I've ever seen this sort of year display when the second year didn't directly follow the first.