# PHP date() fails for high timestamps on 32bit

Tags: php, year2038

I've stumbled upon this issue:

```
<?php

echo date('r', 4567743118);
```

Desired & correct result (on localhost):

> Sun, 30 Sep 2114 10:31:58 +0100

Incorrect result (on remote):

> Thu, 24 Aug 1978 04:03:42 +0100

The bad result is obtained when running the script on a 32bit platform. I think it's the famous Y2038 issue, but how should I fix it?

If I echo the timestamp (when stored in variable), it shows fine, but `date()` destroys it (casting to int32, I assume).

```
<?php
$a = 4567743118;
echo $a;
```

> 4567743118

[if relevant, it's PHP 5.4.4 from debian repos]

Comment: Similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it

Comment: Everything about y2038 is "similar", but this ain't really relevant. I need to format those timestamps.

Comment: What is the result of `date('r', '4567743118');`?

Comment: @ManeatingKoala It's the same, 'Thu, 24 Aug 1978 04:03:42 +0100'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$dt = new DateTime('@4567743118');
$date = $dt->format('Y-m-d');

echo $date;
```

<kbd>[**run code on x86 machine**](https://eval.in/209758)</kbd>

Comment: Excellent, this works. I've made a wrapper function `fdate()` for it.

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp on a 32bit system goes only untill *2.147.483.647*. So if you have a bigger value you come over the integer maximal length. The maximum here is the year 2038.

If you need bigger dates you have to use datetime.