# False year inserted in SQL table

Tags: mysql, drupal, timestamp

The `timestamp` of the nodes in my node table have year as 201 instead of 2014 which are stored in `unixtime`. Is there a way in which I can update only  the year of all the nodes concerned?

Comment: provide some sample data of those 201 related unixtime.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL timestamp field allows a range of values between -2147483648 and 2147483648. (A detailed explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2012620/3084708).) The Unix time equivalent of "201-01-01 00:00:00" is 
-55824249600. So, MySQL timestamp field cannot save a date from year 201.

If my above assumption is wrong and a date from year 201 exists in a timestamp field on your database, I think the best solution is;

- Calculate the interval between 201-01-01 00:00:00 and 2014-01-01 00:00:00 in seconds:

  ```
  1388534400 - (-55824249600) = 57212784000
  ```
- Add this value to all "created" fields in your "node" table with the following SQL query:

  ```
  UPDATE node SET created = created + 57244320000;
  ```