# strtotime not working for long time addition

Tags: php, date, strtotime, dateadd

I need a date which is 35 years ahead of a date which is user input.
With the following code in php

`$DoCndm=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['DoH'] ." +35 years"));`

I found that it works correctly upto 22 years but returns output as 1970-01-01 for 23 and above.. Is it a bug ??

Comment: Its 64 bit, with wamp64

Comment: besides the duplicate found for this, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it

Comment: Can you `echo PHP_INT_SIZE;`

Comment: its **4** only...so does wamp 64 has 32 bit php?

Answer (score 3):

Read this link [Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

You can not use unix timstamp above 2038 year