# Storing a timestamp in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

If I generate a timestamp with PHP's `time()` and insert/update a row with it, what column type should I use?

I've used `varchar(20)` (64-bit) in the past, and I tried `TIMESTAMP` just then and it has the year 2038 error it seems.

Is it okay to just use `varchar(20)` to store a timestamp?

Comment: Is it ok.. that's pretty opinion based.. But storing it in only varchar 20 will get you in troubles in the future..

Comment: Timestamp is an integer, so why wouldn't you store it as an integer in the DB?

Comment: use DATETIME datatype !

Comment: unsigned int would work, otherwise a bigint. Both are smaller than a `VARCHAR(20)`.

Comment: Please read this SO question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-field-datetime-or-timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use DATETIME datatype,

MySQL retrieves and displays `DATETIME` values in `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` format. The supported range is `'1000-01-01 00:00:00'` to `'9999-12-31 23:59:59'` .

The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of `'1970-01-01 00:00:01'` UTC to `'2038-01-19 03:14:07'` UTC.

you may also go through this,

[PHP & mySQL: Year 2038 Bug: What is it? How to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it)

Answer (score 0):

Use DATETIME as datatype and use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` with the time as optional parameter to insert into the column. See http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for more info on the date function.