# year 2038 issue - 64 bit (Linux OS, php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, linux

`select unix_timestamp('2038-01-19')` returns `2147472000`

while `select unix_timestamp('2038-01-20')` returns `0`

I have checked out the year `2038` problem.

My linux OS is 64 bit and installed mysql version is also 64 bits. What is the solution to this problem now?

`mysql --version` returns `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.47, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

Php is 64 bit too.

Tried BigInt too, didn't work (returns the same thing).

Comment: `select unix_timestamp('2038-01-19') returns 2147472000`
`while select unix_timestamp('2038-01-19') returns 0` can you tell what is difference in the two query?

Comment: @Anant that was a typo..thanks

Comment: change it then in your question

Comment: it's updated...thanks

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` expects a date. If you feed it with strings you rely on implicit type casts. You'll probably get a more coherent solution if you first clarify on what precise date type you want to operate.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález nope, it returns zero if I don't pass string to it.

Comment: "Tried BigInt too, didn't work (returns the same thing)." -- What exactly did you try, in the context of the original question?

Comment: Not sure I follow you now. It returns zero because the output type is probably a 32-bit integer, not because you pass a string. Just pass a date below 2038 and you'll see. It's the same reason why `'3'*'4'` works: implicit casts.

Comment: select unix_timestamp(2038-01-19) returned 0,  select unix_timestamp(2038-01-20) returned zero.. @apokryfos

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález it returns 0 for this too ->select unix_timestamp(2011-01-20)

Comment: the param in unix_timestamp needs to be passed in quotes but yes that should be a valid date format @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: Honestly, I'd say you have to let your users know that they have to accept the limitation of not being able to schedule (?) anything more than 22 years in the future (give or take) until MySQL gets up to speed and starts using 64-bit timestamps.

Comment: Start from MySQL 8.0.28 the functions FROM_UNIXTIME(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), and CONVERT_TZ() now handle 64-bit values on platforms that support them, including 64-bit versions of Linux, MacOS, and Windows.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-28.html#mysqld-8-0-28-feature

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put, for `MySQL`, store dates as `DATETIME` rather than `TIMESTAMP`.

TIMESTAMP is 4 bytes, so there is no physical room to store more seconds than since 1970-1-1 to 2038-01-19...

DATETIME, instead, has a range of 1000-1-1 to 9999-12-31...

See also this *complete* question/answer: [PHP & mySQL: Year 2038 Bug: What is it? How to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it)

**UPDATE**:
One possible alternative I see, if you CAN'T change your fields types, is to **interpet** your timestamps differently...
I mean: if the **first** event your application will keep track of is - say - `2000-1-1`, you could implement a filter on backend (or in a stored procedure *inside* the database), to add (`2000-1-1` - `1970-1-1`) seconds to your timestamps when reading, and subtract the same amount when reading... This should give you 30 more years of 'survival'...

Comment: We have kept it as INT in our database, don't want to redesign it.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo: And I don't want to pay my rent next month. I guess we'll both have to be unhappy. *shrug*

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The application is in UAT. All of the tables store date in INT format, I can't risk the deadline. Though I know, datetime would solve the issue

Comment: :-))) A MySQL `INT` is 4 bytes, so you physically CAN'T store more than 2,147,483,648 seconds, sorry...

Comment: gives the same output @MarcoS

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` expects no parameter or one `date` parameter... See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Answer (score 4):

MySQL documentation is in general extremely vague about the data types returned by functions and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is not an exception. Unless we check the source code I think we can only make an educated guess.

At [Date and Time Type Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html) we can read that the `TIMESTAMP` data type itself has a documented range that doesn't depend on the server architecture:

> The range is '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000' UTC to
>   '2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999' UTC. TIMESTAMP values are stored as the
>   number of seconds since the epoch ('1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC). A
>   TIMESTAMP cannot represent the value '1970-01-01 00:00:00' because
>   that is equivalent to 0 seconds from the epoch and the value 0 is
>   reserved for representing '0000-00-00 00:00:00', the “zero” TIMESTAMP
>   value.

Even if we make sure we pass a proper date type:

```
mysql> select
    ->  str_to_date('2038-01-20', '%Y-%m-%d'),
    ->  unix_timestamp(str_to_date('2038-01-20', '%Y-%m-%d'));
+---------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('2038-01-20', '%Y-%m-%d') | unix_timestamp(str_to_date('2038-01-20', '%Y-%m-%d')) |
+---------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 2038-01-20                            |                                                     0 |
+---------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

... we still get `0`, the silly function flag for errors:

> If you pass an out-of-range date to UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), it returns 0.

So it's kind of safe to assume that `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` returns a value of `TIMESTAMP` type thus 2038+ is not supported.

In short: you'll have to calculate timestamps somewhere else (i.e., your client code). Since there's a PHP tag:

```
$t = new DateTime('2038-01-20', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump( $t->format('U') );
```

> string(10) "2147558400"

---

P.S. MariaDB, the MySQL fork, has the same restriction but it [documents it](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/unix_timestamp/) better:

> Timestamps in MariaDB have a maximum value of 2147483647, equivalent
>   to 2038-01-19 05:14:07. This is due to the underlying 32-bit
>   limitation. Using the function on a date beyond this will result in
>   NULL being returned.

Comment: the value return by  2038-01-19 is same as 2147472000

Comment: We'd need to know the time zone and where/how you calculate that figure. Are you referring to my PHP snippet? :-?

Comment: I am executing this sql query in mysql client. I have bought Amazon's instance with linux on it.

Comment: If you run `SELECT unix_timestamp(str_to_date('2038-01-19', '%Y-%m-%d'))` in your Amazon MySQL service and you get `2147472000` that means your server time zone is UTC. Is that a problem of some kind? Do you have a followup question or something?