# php strtotime wrong value

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, strtotime

I have this code:

```
$date_parsed = strtotime($answer['answer']);
$required_date_parsed = strtotime('-16 years');

if ($date_parsed > $required_date_parsed) {
    $row = null;
    break 1;
}
```

And for some reason `2041-11-30` does not go into the if statement while it is obviously bigger than 16 years ago. Dates like `1980-04-18` do go into the if block as they should. Why is this happening?

Comment: 32-bit signed integer limits for timestamps.... [Year 2038 Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).... consider using DateTime objects instead, as they are 64-bit internally

Comment: Ah, how can I turn it into 64 bit?

Comment: Install a 64-bit version of PHP, or use DateTime objects instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it

Comment: Thanks everyone :D