# Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm getting this error when I insert these value into my database table:

> ```
> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value:
> '24/06/2017' for column 'registration_from' at row 1 
> (SQL: insert into `campus_registrations` (`campus_major_class_id`, 
> `registration_from`, `registration_to`, `testing`, `announcement`, 
> `enrollment_from`, `enrollment_to`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (3, 
> 24/06/2017, 27/06/2017, 13/07/2017, 01/08/2017, 05/09/2017, 31/01/2018,
>  2017-06-07 09:39:31, 2017-06-07 09:39:31))
> ```

Do I have to intiate the datetime first or what?

Comment: first add your table schema into question.

Comment: @kRicha they're all datetime

Comment: @goateee25 try to use this format `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error is here:

```
Incorrect datetime value: '24/06/2017' for column 'registration_from' at row 1
```

the default format for `date` column in mysql is `Y-m-d` and for `datetime` is `Y-m-d H:i:s`. So change your date to this format and try again.

Answer (score 31):

I got the same error while trying to register user from the vue js frontend to laravel backend API.

The solution was updating the mysql strict mode to false. If anyone knows the cons of this approach, please leave your comments!

```
//config/database.php
'mysql' => [
    'strict' => false,
]
```

Comment: The downside is that if the date doesn't match with this format `Y-m-d`, instead of throwing an error, MySQL will insert something like this in place of the provided date `0000-00-00`.

Answer (score 15):

Since you're not using standard datetime format, [define a mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) for each date. For example:

```
public function setRegistrationFromAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['registration_from'] =  Carbon::parse($value);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Don't forget about Y2K38(Year 2038 problem) -

`timestamp` has a limit of `1970-01-01 00:00:01` UTC to `2038-01-19 03:14:07` UTC (source), whilst `dateTime` has a range of `1000-01-01 00:00:00` to `9999-12-31 23:59:59`, so consider what you plan on storing in that field before determining which type to use.

`timestamp` and `dateTime` are similar - they store a date `(YYYY-MM-DD)` and time `(HH:MM:SS)` together in a single field i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. The difference between the two is that timestamp can use (MySQL's) `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as its value, whenever the database record is updated. This can be handled at the database level and is great for Laravel's `created_at` and `updated_at` fields.

date stores just the date component i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD` (`1000-00-01` to `9999-12-31`).

`timestamps` doesn't take an argument, it's a shortcut to add the `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamp fields to your database.

So setting a date on timestamp bigger than `2038-01-19 03:14:07 UTC` will also throw - `SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value`

Comment: Does anybody know if this Y2K38 will be updated to some bigger range? nice catch though! ***thanks***.

Comment: there are solutions to solve this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2012620/2335493)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and finally i solved the problem.Yoou can add the few line of code at the end of the add.blade.php

```
 $('.date-picker').datepicker({
                format: 'yy/mm/dd',
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

MYSQL recognises date value in either `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YY-MM-DD` format. You can use `/`. This `24/06/2017` considered invalid. Try `2017/06/24`

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me under laravel 5.6, until I changed the code to 
`$table->date('last_date')->default(now());`

Answer (score 0):

1. I've dropped problem column in new migration:

`$table->dropColumn('time_to_deliver');`

2. created new migration file and now instead of 'timestamp' put in 'time' as the type:

`$table->time('time_to_deliver')->nullable()->after('date_to_deliver');`

3. in next migration file have done next(within a loop):

`$orderLcl = new Order;// a Model`

`$orderLcl->time_to_deliver = date("H:i",$mock_timestampLcl);`

```
.....
$orderLcl->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to insert date time.

```
$item->date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($request->date));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem importing Excel data, but I finally solved the problem. This happens because my Excel language is English (US) and the default database format is Y-M-D, which means English (UK). So, you should change your language to English.
(UK) That is fine work.

Answer (score -2):

If the column has default set to NULL, you can probably do something like this in your code:

```
$model->column = NULL;
```

Comment: Not the answer expecting