# I am coverting unix timestamp to Datetime format in mysql .But it is showing NULL as an output

Tags: mysql

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(32154654321);
```

Output:Null

Expected Result: Tuesday, December 9, 2988 1:55:21 PM GMT+05:30

Answer (score 2):

This is the [Year-2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). The maximum value of the `TIMESTAMP` datatype is `2038-01-19 03:14:07`, so you can't get the expected result.

> **MySQL 5.5:** The `TIMESTAMP` data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. `TIMESTAMP` has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.
>   **source:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html
>
> **MySQL 5.6+:** [...] and the range for `TIMESTAMP` values is '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000' to '2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999'.
>   **source:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

You can find a very [good answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2012620/3840840) with some more details about this problem.

---

You can use PHP instead of MySQL to convert the timestamp (not stored in a `TIMESTAMP` column) to a readable datetime, with the following code:

```
$timestamp = 32154654321;
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($timestamp);
echo $date->format($format);
```

> **demo:** http://ideone.com/DsYUOQ

Answer (score 2):

This is why: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Comment: The timestamp 1499683065229 showing also null output even the year associated with this timestamp  is 2017.

Comment: that's `Mon, 23 Jan 49493 21:13:49 GMT`, according to http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm. I think you also have milliseconds in that format. Try dividing by 1000. Current timestamp is `1499844066`

Comment: I am referring https://www.epochconverter.com/ and according to this timestamp 1499683065229 GMT: Monday, July 10, 2017 10:37:45.229 AM
Your time zone: Monday, July 10, 2017 4:07:45.229 PM GMT+05:30.

Comment: this is the output of https://www.epochconverter.com/ `Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds: GMT: Monday, July 10, 2017 10:37:45.229 AM`. Timestamps _do not_ have milliseconds. Since they're both numbers, why would 1499844065 == 1499683065229?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot input like 32154654321

> Timestamps in mysql have a maximum value of 2147483647, equivalent
>   to 2038-01-19 05:14:07. This is due to the underlying 32-bit
>   limitation. Using the function on a timestamp beyond this will result
>   in NULL being returned. Use DATETIME as a storage type if you require
>   dates beyond this.