# PHP year 2038 problem with 64bit MySQL can't insert date through PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL table which has a column called "created_at" which is a TIMESTAMP field. Whenever I try to insert datetime bigger than 2037 I get the following error:

```
#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '2039-06-18 16:54:35' for column 'created_at' at row 1
```

I get that this a problem with 32bit MySQL but I am running 64bit shouldn't that be the solution?

Here is the output of the command for the version of my MySQL:

```
mysqld  Ver 5.7.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it) suggesting that using the TIMESTAMP field is the problem and using DATETIME fields will solve it, is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TIMESTAMP remains UNIX TIMESTAMP (32Bit) for compatibility reasons...

The suggestion you've read is correct, use DATETIME instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `DATETIME` data type.

> [The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)
>
> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to **'2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.**