# Incorrect date time value for mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, datetime, timestamp, faker

I was trying to seed laravel app with faker and their is a column `valid_to` where I did try to use below code and got the error as following:
error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: 
Invalid datetime format: 
1292 Incorrect datetime value: 
'2039-01-16 15:21:43' for column 'valid_to'
```

code:

```
 $faker->dateTimeBetween($startDate = 'now', $endDate = '+20 years', $timezone = null),
```

Issue is, as I changed to `+20 years` to `+10 years, the code is working.
below is the code which worked for me.

```
 $faker->dateTimeBetween($startDate = 'now', $endDate = '+10 years', $timezone = null),
```

Is this the limitation for `timestamp` field in `DB (Mysql)` ?

Comment: Yep. The REAL millennium bug

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP & mySQL: Year 2038 Bug: What is it? How to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it)

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

You should use `DATETIME`, not `TIMESTAMP`.