# Dates after 01-01-2039 converted in PHP is shown as 01-01-1970

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have converted a date 01-01-2039 using php date() function:

```
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime('01-01-2039'));
```

Output is shown as: 01-01-1970

Any solution for this?

Comment: Using that simple example works as expected when tried [here](http://phptester.net/).

Comment: This is the [Unix Timestamp Epoch problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Comment: @PaulT. your link doesn't go to any code

Comment: @Martin ... can't store code at that site, I simply copy/pasted that one line, and clicked run.

Comment: Whart version of PHP are you using? You probably need to either update your PHP version or update your php.ini settings . You may also need to update your OS to being a 64bit system

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP & mySQL: Year 2038 Bug: What is it? How to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it)

Comment: I have Windows 10 64 bit system & PHP version is 7.3.2. @Martin

Comment: @SujithKamath try [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/864402/3536236) to update your PHP.ini

Comment: You will need the 64 bit version of PHP as well

Comment: check: `echo (PHP_INT_SIZE===8)?"64 bit ":"32 bit ";`

Comment: @Martin The PHP is 32 bit version (x86). Hence the problem i guess.

Comment: Yes, that's the cause. You need to uninstall and reinstall PHP as the 64 bit version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *This Answer from comment conversation*

The problem is caused by the [Unix Timestamp Epoch problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

The solution to this for native PHP is to use the 64bit PHP version that correctly handles this particular integer overflow.

```
echo (PHP_INT_SIZE===8)?"64 bit ":"32 bit ";
```

This above code shows the PHP version.

If 32bit PHP is present then that needs to be replaced by the 64bit PHP

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Martin's answer, I want to point out the ambiguity caused by some date formats when using [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

In the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Dates in the *m/d/y* or *d-m-y* formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American *m/d/y* is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European *d-m-y* format
>   is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and
>   the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as *y-m-d*.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (*YYYY-MM-DD*)
>   dates or [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) when possible.

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '01-01-2039');
echo $dt->format('d-m-Y');
```